# How to attach external disk to Windows VM in Azure without losing data?

Tags: windows, azure, formatting, disk, hard-drive

I'm looking for how to attach an existing external disk from VM1 to VM2 without formatting it from the Manager disk in Windows.

All the documentation that I find tells to format it at the end. I need to recover all the data that exists in the disk, not erase them.

Answer (score 0):

Once the Disk is detached from VM1, you can easily re-attach it to another VM (VM2), without formatting, with the following Powershell : [Attach an existing data disk to a VM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/attach-disk-ps#attach-an-existing-data-disk-to-a-vm).